# Stack JPanel cards from top to bottom inside a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, awt

I need to dynamically stack panels inside another one, but instead filling it from center, I need to add cards ( panels ) and they going to top of the container.

Much more like this:
http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Swing_How_to/Layout/Force_components_to_be_stacked_from_top_not_vertically_centered_with_GridBagLayout.htm

and this:
[GridBagLayout - Vertically positioning components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49330716/gridbaglayout-vertically-positioning-components)

But I can't addapt the code to allow dynamically inserts of new JPanels.

This is what I have so far:

```
    private JLabel addVesselPane(String text) {
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;       
        
        JLabel vesselLabel = new JLabel( text, JLabel.LEFT );
        vesselLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 9));
        vesselLabel.setOpaque(true);
        vesselLabel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);   
        
        JPanel jp = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
        jp.setBorder( BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder() );
        jp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(190,30));
        jp.add( vesselLabel );
        
        westContentPanel.add(jp, gbc);      
        this.frame.revalidate();    
        return vesselLabel;
    }
```

where:

```
GridBagLayout grid = new GridBagLayout();
westContentPanel = new JPanel( grid );
JScrollPane westScrollPanel = new JScrollPane(westContentPanel);
```

but when I ...

```
for( int x=0; x < 5; x++ ) {
    addVesselPane("Btn " + x);
}
```

The result is:

[image]

When I expect all panels being at the top of the blue panel. I must say when I have more panels than the blue panel can hold, the scroller is activated and I can scroll down. I must be allowed to delete panels too.

Comment: By default a GridBagLayout will display the component in the center, unless one of th the component uses the "weighty" constraint, so you would need to add a dummy component to the bottom of the panel.. An easier approach is to  use a "wrapper" panel. The wrapper panel can use a BorderLayout. Then you add your westScrollPanel to the BorderLayout.PAGE_START. Add the wrapper panel to the frame. Now the components will display from the top.

Comment: You should NOT set the size of anything. Application can run on different screens with different resolutions so they need to be flexible and adjust. Each layout manager is designed for different functionality. That is why many also have constraints so you can customize the behaviour. This makes them very flexible and powerful.  You need to use the appropriate layout manager or combination of layout managers.

Comment: All Swing programmers who commented on my questions have a bad habit of saying what I should't do, but none have the ability to type a single line of code to show the solution with "appropriate layout manager or combination of layout managers". Three times I showed the code. If I should't do this way, show us better. You Swing guys are too theoretical.

Comment: *and know nothing about Swing.* - which is why you have been given suggestions on how to use Swing effectively. Don't blame Swing for your lack of knowledge. *Three times I showed the code.* - you showed a few lines of random code. We need the full context to give a complete answer. This is called an [mre]. Because an MRE was not provided I gave you a verbal explanation of how to use layout managers to achieve you desired effect, which you did incorporate in your answer. You are welcome.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved:

```
    public void addScrollFrame( JPanel toWho, JPanel buttonPanel ) {
        JButton btnAddType = new JButton("Add");
        btnAddType.addActionListener( e -> {
            JLabel card = addNewCard("This is a new Card!");
            // Store it for future reference (Ex. change label)
        });
        buttonPanel.add(btnAddType);

        JButton btnDeleteField = new JButton("Del");
        buttonPanel.add(btnDeleteField);

        JButton btnSaveRule = new JButton("Save");
        buttonPanel.add(btnSaveRule);
        
        this.westContentPanel = new JPanel();
        westContentPanel.setLayout( new BoxLayout( westContentPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS)  );
        
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(westContentPanel);
        scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy( JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER );
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        
        scroll.setViewportView(westContentPanel); 
        toWho.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private JLabel addNewCard(String text) {
        JLabel vesselLabel = new JLabel( text, JLabel.LEFT );
        vesselLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 10));
        vesselLabel.setOpaque(true);
        vesselLabel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        vesselLabel.setCursor( new Cursor( Cursor.HAND_CURSOR ) );
        vesselLabel.setBorder( BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 3, 0, 0) );
        vesselLabel.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(200,35) );
        
        JPanel jp = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
        jp.setMaximumSize( new Dimension(200,35) );
        jp.setBorder( BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
            BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(3, 0, 0, 0), BorderFactory.createLineBorder( Color.BLACK )
        ));
        jp.add( vesselLabel );
        this.westContentPanel.add(jp);      
        this.frame.revalidate();    
        return vesselLabel;
    }
```

`toWho` is a Panel to use as container and `buttonPanel`  a panel to use as button bar.

```
        JPanel westButtonsPanel = new JPanel();
        westButtonsPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(220,40));
        westButtonsPanel.setBorder( BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder() );

        JPanel west = new JPanel(  );
        west.setLayout( new BorderLayout(0, 0) );
        west.setBorder( BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder() );
        west.add(westButtonsPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        addScrollFrame(west, westButtonsPanel);
```

[image]

With scroll !! Just what I need !!

[image]

***Note:*** You may want `westContentPanel` to be created local at `addScrollFrame` scope and passed as parameter to `addNewCard()`. You choose.

Comment: as already commented to your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/q/75880709/203657 it's __wrong__ to hard-code sizing hints

Comment: Good to know it's wrong. Tested on 8 different types of monitors, with different resolutions, on Windows 10, Ubuntu and CentOS. AND STILL WORKING ABSOLUTELY WELL. Sorry, but I must accept.

Comment: And for those who came here looking for help with the same problem and couldn't find anyone smarter than me to tell you the correct way to do it and bother to type some code, use this one.